# What is the word that describes someone only willing to be generous when it comes to their own needs?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Such a person spares no expense when it comes to luxuries yet refuses to part with even a penny when someone else's needs (especially of those who are poor) are concerned?

> In spite of being a millionaire, he is [a] [noun or adjective].

Comment: What research have you done to attempt to find such a word?

Comment: ***Selfish***. And @Hank I have asked the question you just asked many, many times. Several times today. But I usually give a pass to *reverse* dictionary searches, because so far as I'm aware, there is no effective way to research them, given there's nowhere really to begin, and no useful general references aside from plugging the desired meaning into the google search bar.

Comment: @DanBron But sometimes plugging into a search bar is helpful. Like what I did to find the word [Miser](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/miser), which doesn't fully encapsulate the spending on themselves, but just classifies someone who hates spending in general. And I see way too often where suggestions are made and rejected because the OP has already seen them in a search, but they haven't said it in the post. I think research is still necessary to show.

Comment: @Hank Fair enough.

Comment: 'Mean' and synonyms.

Comment: I'd go for two terms: he is a self-indulgent misanthrope.

Comment: maybe a wastrel?

Answer (score 1):

**Self-charitable** comes to mind. It is not in the dictionary; however, "*self-charity*" is a term William Shakespeare used in *Othello*.

**Self-indulgent** could be used as well, but it would have to be qualified.

Comment: Not sure either convey the idea of being miserly with regards to others. Could one not be both self-indulgent and indulgent towards others or does the former preclude the latter?

Comment: @TonyLinde As I mentioned earlier, the second one would need to be qualified. As for self-charity, stinginess towards others is sort of implied, I would think. If you can think of a single Latinate word reflecting the same sentiment, feel free to supply it: I'm always eager to learn. I'm not being sarcastic.

Comment: no, I couldn't either, 'self-indulgent misanthrope' was the closest I could think of. I'd be wary of 'self-charitable', in normal use anyway: I'd never come across it and would probably need some qualification to figure out what was meant in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a **miser**, someone who hoards their money.

Comment: [The Cambridge English Dictionary defines “miser”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/miser) as “someone who has a great desire to possess money and hates to spend it, ***sometimes living like a poor person because of this***” (emphasis added).  Other dictionaries give similar definitions.  A miser typically wouldn’t spend money even on purchases for him/herself.

Answer (score 0):

**Greedy**:

### Definitions

> "1.1 Having or showing an intense and selfish desire for wealth or power."[OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greedy)
>
> "2: marked by greed : having or showing a selfish desire for wealth and possessions"[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greedy)

For completeness, definition for *selfish*:

> "If you say that someone is selfish, you mean that he or she cares only about himself or herself, and not about other people."[CD](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/selfish)

### Examples from [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greedy):

> ‘Therefore many **greedy** landlords do not do repairs, unless forced to.’[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greedy)
>
> ‘In fact our rulers are **greedy** for even more to go into their pockets at our expense.’[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greedy)
>
> ‘Thus, banks became **greedy**, taking on huge risks in hopes of even bigger rewards.’[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/greedy)

### Your sentence

> In spite of being a millionaire, he is **greedy**.

Or a bit more poetically:

> In spite of being a millionaire, he is **driven by greed**.

Driven by greed mentioned [by Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/greed)